# how to run a query with "multiple orderbychild" in realtime database on firebase v9 not v8

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

example :

```
"USA": {
  "-N0QVhkDUxgrHQhS15B7": {
    "State" : 0,
    "Date" : 20220427
  "-N0Vut4beTbYTXihw0KM": {
    "State" : 1,
    "Date" : 20220429
  },
  "-N0W4oWNsgnKYmjPAfhl": {
    "State" : 1,
    "Date" : 20220427
  },
},
```

above is database for example.

```
var ordersRef = query(
  ref(db, "StoreOrders/" + "USA"),
  orderByChild("State"),
  equalTo(1),
  orderByChild("Date")
);
```

I had run this above query. but, below error was occured

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: orderByChild: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls. Reference impl.ts:164
```

how can i solve this problem? this verion is 9. Please let me know correct answer.

Comment: You cannot add multiple `orderBy()` in a query. V9 is just the SDK version. Checkout the alternatives ways to run such queries in the linked answers.

Comment: Going forward: please don't repost the same problem multiple times. At best they will get closed (as happened here), but it may actually get you banned from the site. --- If you don't think your question is a duplicate of what Dharmaraj (or Doug on the [earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72065389/209103)) linked, respond in the comments to explain why it isn't or (even better) edit your original question to show how what you're trying to do is different from the link.